# Sidekick Cloud Builds: Unable to find a specification for `Firebase/Core`

Tags: firebase, build, cloud, nativescript

Since the tns-plugin-firebase update to version 15. When doing sidekick cloud builds I receive the message:
Unable to find a specification for `Firebase/Core` -> 5.5

I followed the intructions fron the community which basically tells to do pods repo update, I even rm -rf the .cocoapods folder and reinstall it.

When building locally it works, but when doing cloud builds with sidekick I received the abve mentioned message.

Is possibl that the pods repo update has to be done in the sidekick server too?, because if not I don´t have a clue why this is happening!!!

Thanks for ideas or hints.

Javier

Answer (score 2):

The issue is indeed related to the Sidekick cloud build service. The pods management is done entirely on the cloud machines, even when you build from a macOS system.

Having said that, the pod is now updated to the latest available version and after a couple of hours (time needed to propagate the changes to the entire infrastructure), you should no longer experience the "Unable to find a specification for Firebase/Core -> 5.5" error while building for iOS in the cloud.

Comment: Thanks GCarabedian, it seems does it works, because I am getting another error!!!!